# i have a problem with travis ci node js jwt

Tags: node.js, jwt, travis-ci

When i run a test in Travis that requires JWT token verification, the test fails, i get error from the JWT code
but in local test, it works

```
// JWT function
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined) {
      next();
    }
    const decode = jwt.verify(req.body.token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
    req.userData = decode;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: 'failed',
      error: 'Invalid Request Token',
    });
  }
};
```

Calling the verify below

`````
router.get('/', verify, (req, res) => {
  viewtrips().then((result) => {
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      result,
    });
  });
});
````
I get the 409 error inside the JWT in Travis
but it works well in local test
`````